# Проблемка с jquery, функция .click

Tags: jquery

Сделал вот такую [штуку](http://jsfiddle.net/c5x9p/).
После нажатия на кнопку появляется блок, если по этому блоку кликнуть, он "перепоявится", из-за этого невозможно взаимодействовать с элементами внутри этого блока.
Подскажите как исправить?

Comment: откуда вы взяли второй аргумент у [.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте переопределить `click` у внутреннего контента, например [так](http://jsfiddle.net/Uuf7n/1/):

```
...
$(
$('<div id="show_block"<form><textarea></textarea><input type="submit"></form></div>')
.click(function(){return false;})
).appendTo(this,'.button');
...
```

Comment: При использовании этого способа, не будут работать ссылки и кнопки, которые находятся внутри `.show_block`.

Comment: Логично :-)

Answer (score 3):

Так как вы "навешиваете" событие `click` на эллементы с классом `.button`, то оно будет срабатывать и при нажатии на дочерние эллементы, которым и является эллемент с классом `show_block`.

Для того, что-бы предотвратить исполнение функции при нажатии на дочерний эллемент, нужно проверить класс эллемента, на который нажал пользователь. Для этого используем обьект `event.target`.

Пример: [jsfiddle.net/Uuf7n](http://jsfiddle.net/Uuf7n/)

**(исправленый вариант в комментариях)*

---

Кстати, небольшие поправки к вашему коду:

1. Вместо `$(document).ready(function(){})`, советую использовать `$(function(){})` — так короче.
2. При работе с `jsfiddle`, библиотеку `jquery` можно подключить в левом меню, а не прописывать в `head`.
3. Вместо блоков типа `<div class="clear"></div>`, советую попробовать в родительского эллемента в стилях `overflow:auto` — в большинстве случаев, это решает проблему и делает вёрстку более удобной.

Comment: Спасибо, а вы еще не подскажите, почему в мозиле и эксплорере не работает?

Comment: Да точно, ваше решение не работает в мозиле и эксплорере. Жаль

Comment: я думаю если заменить строчку
**if($(event.target).hasClass('button'))**
на
**if($(this).hasClass('button'))**

работать будет

Comment: Извините, не знал, что `event.target` - не кроссбраузерный обьект. Вот исправленый вариант: [jsfiddle.net/PdNWh](http://jsfiddle.net/PdNWh/)

Answer (score 1):

Измени разметку - оберни `div.click` и выпадалки вставляй в родительский `div`